# How to set up google cloud account for python?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I have created a google cloud bucket.

Now I would like to get access to it trough python.

I have installed locally `google-cloud-storage` trough

`pip install google-cloud-storage`

And I have defined all the credentials and the name of the bucket. This what I am doing:

```
from google.cloud import storage
client = storage.Client()
bucket_id = 'myBucket'
bucket = client.get_bucket(bucket_id)
```

this what I get

```
DefaultCredentialsError: Could not automatically determine credentials. Please set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS or explicitly create credentials and re-run the application. For more information, please see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started
```

Comment: Did you try to do what the error message says?

Comment: @MadPhysicist yes but I do not find the .json file with the account key

Comment: @emax Maybe you forgot to create the service account and download the json file: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-usage-python

Comment: yes sorry, just realized that

Answer (score 0):

As Scratch'N'Purr mentioned,

you need to setup the authentication as [mentioned here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#setting_up_authentication)

Then your script will use the credentials given to access the resource on GCP.

Regards,

Frederic